# Error in py2app application

Tags: macos, import, py2app, attributeerror

(OSX = Mountain lion) My app in /dist throws the error:

```
Last login: Wed Aug 28 11:21:29 on ttys001
-MacBook-Pro:~ $ /Users/Desktop/dist/abc.app/Contents/MacOS/abc ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2app/apptemplate/lib/site.py", line 20, in   <module>
import os
 File "os.pyc", line 398, in <module>
 File "UserDict.pyc", line 83, in <module>
 File "_abcoll.pyc", line 11, in <module>
 File "/Users/Virendra/Desktop/dist/abc.app/Contents/Resources/abc.py", line 6, in <module>
import psutil 
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/psutil/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/psutil/_common.py", line 16, in <module>
 File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/psutil/_compat.py", line 65, in <module>
 File "collections.pyc", line 6, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
 logout
```

My setup.py (same error even without the - 'import os') looks like:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
python setup.py py2app
```

"""

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['abc.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['psutil', 'time', 'socket', 'os']}

setup(
   app=APP,
   data_files=DATA_FILES,
   options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
   setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

And the scrip abc.py in question:

```
    from psutil import cpu_times_percent 
    import socket
    import time


    serverHost = "localhost"
    thisClient = socket.gethostname()
    cpuStats = psutil.cpu_times_percent()
    print cpuStats
    currentTime = int(time.time())
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((serverHost,8080))
    command = 'put cpu.usr ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[0]) + " host="+ thisClient+ "\n" 
    s.sendall(command)
    command = 'put cpu.nice ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[1]) +" host="+ thisClient+ "\n"
    s.sendall(command)
    command = 'put cpu.sys ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[2]) + " host="+ thisClient+ "\n"
    s.sendall(command)
    command = 'put cpu.idle ' + str(currentTime) + " " + str(cpuStats[3]) + " host="+     thisClient+ "\n"
    s.sendall(command)
    s.close()
```

Initially it was 'import psutil' which I changed to the 'from psutil...' as above. Included the 'import os...' here. But all combinations throw the same error. Elsewhere, I have seen 'import psutil' as a standard import and this is no different. What else could the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'` mean? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script file, `abc.py`, conflicts with the [Python standard library Abstract Base Class module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), `abc`.  The simplest solution should be to just change the name of your file to something else.

Comment: Thx. It worked! But I am getting a new (albeit unrelated to the original issue) error as follows: [It lists the cpupercent at the top but goes on to detail the error - I am not following the output here - Any help/explanation is much appreciated ]    $ ./dist/test1.app/Contents/MacOS/test1
cpupercent(user=2.4, nice=0.0, system=4.8, idle=92.9)
Traceback (most recent call last): [includes only the last part]
 line 16, in <module>
    s.connect((serverHost,4242))
  File "socket.pyc", line 224, in meth
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
2013-08-28 12:50:25.104 test1[4519:707] test1 Error

Comment: Please don't ask new, unrelated questions in comments.  They will likely be overlooked and any discussion won't include or benefit others.  You should open a new question.  That said, "connection refused" seems pretty clear.  You need to make sure you can establish a connection to the server application, what ever it is, at the network address contained in `serverHost` at port 4242. But, again, open a new question if you are still having problems.

Comment: Okay. Thx. Let me check with a different port and will update as advised.